# OAuth Consumer Library for Obj-c that works with many service providers

Tags: iphone, twitter, ios, oauth

I'm developing an iOS app that needs to connect to Twitter, Facebook, Google, Yahoo, Gowalla and Foursquare via OAuth. I have been using http://github.com/dbloete/oauth-objc and that works fine with Twitter (OAuth v.1, basic implementation), but has problems with everything else (it seems that each provider has different standards for signing requests).

I understand that the Java library signpost does a good job of abstracting away the pain of OAuth over multiple service providers. Is there something like this for Objective-C ?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/, should be what you are looking for..

Comment: unfortunately that lib has its own problems, specifically with Google. I ended up hacking what I had been using.